# How can I persuade my manager to change my project?

Tags: manager, projects

I joined a decent company almost a year back, SDE profile, and was recently(~1 month) assigned a project which does not align at all with my skills.

I admit I am fresh out of college but the assigned role is literally a Data Entry job (no disrespect to the job), keeping count of all people coming in, going out, or are active in a client project. That's it. I was told that this would be great learning while doing opportunity but now it is being said that I have to do this for almost a year or year and a half before any change in roles.

Then a few days back, a project came with very lucrative propositions like location flexibility, preferred skill set, and alignment with my goals.On this project, I have the opportunity to learn and use many new technologies which complement my current skills. But I am facing huge resistance switching to the new project from my current manager. This role I am in is not at all aligned with my skills and goals. The new one is.

Please help me out, how can I persuade my manager to change my project? When I had initial talks with them, I was told I am being ridiculous and 1 month is a short time to judge the role, but I have seen even people with 4-5 years exp in that project doing similar work. Please help because this is really disturbing me that I can't work on things that I am skillful in rather they have sent me a project with 0 growth opportunities. (1 mid-senior Lvl emp who recently left our org was in the same project as me and told me that this place is good for low work but no growth will happen here).
Please help me...

Comment: I suggest you change the title of your question to "How can I persuade my manager to change my project?", that seems to be what you're asking.

Comment: May I suggest this is a good opportunity to try to see what parts of your role may be automated?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I persuade my manager to change my project?

You can't, you're entry level. The manager needs a data entry position filled and is filling it with you. You have no leverage to change this without threatening to quit or something which would probably end badly for you.

The managers primary concern is not necessarily your growth.

Comment: Well the thing is, for the past year or two, that department has been running with that much amount of personnel only. If I was doing any work I would not have complained but I am doing the work which 1 person was doing all this time. That is not even my domain/dept, I have to work as loaned employee and do some one else's work.

Comment: You have already asked and been turned down. You don't get to make any other decisions at your level except when to quit. When easily replaceable people don't want to work, quite often the easiest remedy is to just replace them

Answer (score 0):

Your only real chance is if you can get in touch with whoever is running the new project, and get them to ask for your time.

Whether or not this can work depends on the structure of your company.  If it's big enough, there may be someone whose job it is to ensure that all projects get the people they need.  That person (or group) is who will end up making the decision.

Your existing manager is quite happy with you being stuck doing a tedious job.  It's something that one of their more senior people doesn't have to do.

Comment: The new project manager is quite helpful and even said that he would help me get released but present manager is not budging.

Comment: @FreeMan99 that's why your only chance is for someone higher up in the company to overrule them.